# Test for PHP mail Functionality without calling mail

Tags: php, email

Aside from actually attempting to send an email with [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and checking the returned value for a failed result, is it possible to 'feature detect' whether mail() will work?

If it is not possible, what would be common tell-tale signs that it is likely to fail?

Some scenarios:

- Giving site administrators warning about email configuration errors
- Providing alternate workflows to module users where mail is not available
- Getting around framework mail wrappers that don't suppress errors

EDIT: Some clarification - I'm not trying to test for unreported errors (upstream delivery failures, or any condition that PHP returns true from `mail()`). Basically I'm looking for one or more simple tests that can be performed purely in PHP (or a system call from PHP) that would at least give you a heads-up that called `mail()` is not safe.

Comment: There's no way to 100% prove that `mail()` will work, in that mail will get delivered to its destination.  The MTA that PHP is configured to use might not accept mail from this host for example, or (if it were really mean) it might accept mail and then not deliver it.  I'm not saying there aren't red flags you can check, but you can only check so many things.

Comment: Thanks. Yes aware that all it can do is put the mail into a queue and hope. What I'm really asking is if there is a way to test when mail will trigger an error without calling `mail()`. Silent failures (ie, reports true even though the email never arrives) is beyond what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to programmatically check.  Most of the time on mis-configured servers, `mail()` will appear to succeed just fine, but the message will be sitting in a queue somewhere on the server.

As cdhowie said, even if it did work, you could have other problems upstream.

What you could do is fire off a test e-mail to one of your servers with a random key of some sort in the subject line.  On your server, have some code read these test e-mails and then add them to a database.  Build a simple script that returns a simple yay/nay whether or not the test e-mail was successfully received.  `isitthereyet.php?key=ASDFASDFASDF`

That's probably overkill though for what you want, but the best solution I can think of.

Comment: Heh, yeah overkill, but a good idea anyway. Might be a useful tool for someone to create - a simple web service that receives emails and notifies your app of receipt via RCP or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to check if the mail() exists so it doesn't return undefined function? You could use [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php).

Comment: No, mail is part of the PHP core.

Comment: I guess you could create a function to check the mail ini settings and see if they look fishy. It would probably be hard to tell someone's custom configuration from a misconfigured one. You could maybe go so far as verify sendmail_path exists or even exec the sendmail_path and check it's output to see if it returns something that looks proper.